# How can I see a service's logs when running it from Docker?

Tags: questdb

I'm running questdb in docker with this command:

```sh
docker run -p 9000:9000 -p 8812:8812 -d questdb/questdb
```

How can I check the log output of this service? It's not really convenient for me to write the database logs to disk, but I would like to check for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

When you run this with the `-d` flag, you are running in detached mode, so logs will not be visible in stdout. To check the logs for this container, run

```
docker logs <container_id>
```

You can find out the container ID using:

```sh
docker ps
```